# Mysql invalid use of group function with Count?

Tags: mysql

I am building a game thing and I'm currently working on the matching players mechanism but I get this error I cant figure. I have 2 tables `games` which holds information about different instances of the game and `players` which holds players in each game. Now when a new player joins the matchmaking queue I want to select all games that haven't currently started and add them ( the player ) to the respective game. How I recognize a not-started game is by the number of players in it. If a game is meant for 2 players then any game with 1 player hasn't started yet. And here's my query

```
SELECT * // * for saving time in testing
FROM games d LEFT JOIN players dp ON d.id = dp.gameId 
WHERE d.players > COUNT(dp.playerId) LIMIT 1
```

But I get this annoying error

> ## 1111 - Invalid use of group function

I tried it like this

```
SELECT *, COUNT(dp.playerId) AS cPlayers 
FROM games d LEFT JOIN players dp ON d.id = dp.gameId 
WHERE d.players > cPlayers LIMIT 1
```

but then I get

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'cPlayers' in 'where clause'

Comment: why insist reverting the formatting edit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this should work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM games d LEFT JOIN players dp ON d.id = dp.gameId
GROUP BY d.id
HAVING d.players > COUNT(dp.playerId) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` should be performed on `d.id`

Comment: @zerkms Excellent point. Removed my doubts about why it wasn't using my indexes!

Comment: @zerkms thanks, didn't pay attention, updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

You should use **GROUP BY** on fields to use aggregation functions like COUNT(dp.playerId).

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(dp.playerId) AS cPlayers 
FROM games d LEFT JOIN players dp ON d.id = dp.gameId group by dp.playerId  
WHERE d.players > cPlayers LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` goes **after** `WHERE` PS: it won't run because of usage of `cPlayers` in where

Comment: Will it work if the condition is put in HAVING clause. Like : HAVING d.players > cPlayers

Comment: Then it will work, but you still have wrong `group by` & `where` order